# Symfony 2 and twig: Add a class for 'current page' in navigation

Tags: symfony, twig

So I've built a navigation menu in Symfony 2 and i'm trying to work out how to get it to display a class on the nav item of the current page. I'm pretty good at PHP but I'm very new at Symfony so please make your answers as basic as possible.

Here is my code:

**Template**:

```
{% for nav in navItems %}
    <li>
        <a title="{{ nav.pageName }}" {% //Logic to display class %} class="" {% //endlogic %} href="{{ path('myclient_style_guide_page_elements_show', {'pageUrl': nav.pageUrl}) }}">{{ nav.pageName }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**The two routes for the navigation:**

```
myClient_style_guide_page_elements_show:
    pattern:  /page-elements/{pageUrl}
    defaults: { _controller: myClientStyleGuideBundle:pageElements:show}
    requirements:
        _method:  GET

myClient_style_guide_page_elements_nav:
    pattern:  /page-elements-nav
    defaults: { _controller: myClientStyleGuideBundle:pageElements:nav }
```

**and the controller for the navigation:**

```
 public function navAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $navItems = $em->getRepository('myClientStyleGuideBundle:pageElements')->findBypageParent('page-elements');

        if (!$navItems) throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find any pages under this category');

        return $this->render(
            'myClientStyleGuideBundle:Partial:peNav.html.twig',
            array('navItems' => $navItems)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your view:

```
{% macro is_current_route(route) %} 
    {%- if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == route -%} 
    {{- 'class="active"' -}} {%- else -%} {{- 'class="inactive"' -}} 
    {%- endif -%} 
{% endmacro %}  

{% import _self as croute %}  

{% for nav in navItems %}  
<li>
    <a title="{{ nav.pageName }}"  
        {{- croute.is_current_route('myclient_style_guide_page_elements_show') -}}  
        href="{{ path('myclient_style_guide_page_elements_show', {'pageUrl': nav.pageUrl}) }}"
    > 
        {{ nav.pageName }} 
    </a> 
 </li>  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks man. That doesn't output any errors but it does seem to print "self.is_current_route('myclient_style_guide_page_elements_show')" out into the HTML itself.

Comment: I changed it to:

`<a title="{{ nav.pageName }}" {{ _self.is_current_route('myclient_style_guide_page_elements_show') }} href="{{ path('myclient_style_guide_page_elements_show', {'pageUrl': nav.pageUrl}) }}">{{ nav.pageName }}    </a>`

Just to see what would happen. Now it appears to do nothing. if I remove the _ from before 'self' though I get an error saying "Variable "self" does not exist in..."

Comment: Also updated the macro to this:

`
{% macro is_current_route(route) %}
    {%- if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == route -%}
        {{- 'class="active"' -}}
    {%- else -%}
        {{- 'class="inactive"' -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{% endmacro %}`

and now all the links show as 'class="inactive"'.

Comment: Full code now looks like this:

`{% macro is_current_route(route) %}
    {%- if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == route -%}
        {{- 'class="active"' -}}
    {%- else -%}
        {{- 'class="inactive"' -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as croute %}

{% for nav in navItems %}
    <li>
        <a title="{{ nav.pageName }}" {{ croute.is_current_route('myclient_style_guide_page_elements_show') }} href="{{ path('myclient_style_guide_page_elements_show', {'pageUrl': nav.pageUrl}) }}">{{ nav.pageName }}    </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Oh yes sorry for the typos. I wrote this code without running it, forgot to say it was more "meta" code :) Needed a lot of corrections. I hoped it helped!